# Data Processing in Parallel using Apache Spark with Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a daily level transaction dataset for three months going upto around 17 gb combined. Now I have a server with 16 cores and 64gb RAM with 1 tb of hardisk space. I have the transaction data broken into 90 files each having the same format and a set of queries which is to be run in this entire dataset and the query for each daily level data is the same for all 90 files. The result after the query is run is appended and then we get the resultant summary back. Now before I start on my endevour I was wondering if Apache Spark with pyspark can be used to solve this. I tried R but it was very slow and ultimately I got memory outage issue

So my question has two parts

1. How should I create my RDD? Should I pass my entire dataset as an RDD or is there any way I can tell spark to work in Parallel in these 90 datsets

2.Can I expect a significant speed improvement if I am not working with Hadoop

Comment: The average file size is around 190mb? You should be able to do this using  a Python script with Pandas and processing the files in parallel using a bit of bash. I would recommend not bothering with Spark in this case, it would be like building your own steam train when all you need is to borrow your nephews skateboard.

Comment: Having said that, have a look at Apache Drill, it provides a SQL interface over flat files and is infinitely easier than Spark to get up and running on your server. It would tear through that task.